# Assembly reference failure in VS 2015 RC (works in VS 2013)

Tags: reference, .net-assembly, t4, visual-studio-2015

I created an empty ASP.NET project and added the following T4 template to it:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="Microsoft.Spatial.dll" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
```

I also added NuGet packages Newtonsoft.Json and Microsoft.Spatial. After I compile this project using Visual Studio 2013, I can edit the template file and when I save it the output is correctly generated.

However, if I load the same project into Visual Studio 2015 RC, then the attempt to save the template file result in the following error:

> "Compiling transformation. Metadata file 'Microsoft.Spatial.dll' could
>   not be found."

Note that it's only Microsoft.Spatial.dll that causes the error, Newtonsoft.Json.dll is accepted. And if I prefix Microsoft.Spatial.dll with "$(ProjectDir)bin" then it is accepted.

I would like to avoid using path prefix (because the location of the DLL depends on the project type that I have no control of), but what puzzles me most is why one DLL from a NuGet package can be specified without path prefix, while another DLL causes a failure.

Comment: Do you have a copy of Newtonsoft.Json.dll in the GAC?  If so, T4 is probably using that version and not the one in your project.  Same way it finds "System.Core" without needing a full path.

Comment: Yes, I also think it's using Json.Net from GAC. But I wonder why it worked with VS 2013. Unless of course both assemblies were in GAC on the machine with VS 2013. I will check.

Comment: No I checked both machines where I tested it. None of them has either Newtonsoft.Json or Microsoft.Spatial registered in the GAC. So it must be something else.